# Ubuntu 14.04 (i386) can not accept NVidia Geforce2 MX 400

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

on my old PC (Intel Celeron), 32-bit, Ubuntu 14.04, I have NVidia Geforce2 MX 400  (listed through `lspci -nn | grep '\[03'`)installed.

Though I have installed the newest driver (nvidia-331, from `ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa`), the Nvidia software is not able to detect the graphic card (`nvidia-smi` could not communicate with the driver).

Nvidia-debugdump -l says "driver not loaded". How to enable loading the proper installed nvidia driver ?

I've done a lot of packages (re)installation, but it doesn't help.

Miro

---

Hi again,

upon checking the situation, the /var/log/Xorg.0.log says that I need the legacy nvidia 96.43.xx driver (and this is ubuntu 14.04, i386)

this package is available here (nvidia-96)
http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/i386/nvidia-96/download

but I hit package dependencies... Trying to solve it..

---

Thanks Drac Noc for valuable comment...forcing nvidia-96 on ubuntu 14.04 is wrong way.

In between I switched to the "nouveau" open-source driver, but got the smallest screen resolution...Hmm, looking what to do with this.

Comment: 14.04 dropped support for nvidia-96, you really are coming up against old hardware being "too old" for Ubuntu. Have you considered something like Puppy Linux?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using the 331 driver from the edgers PPA? nvidia-331 is available directly from the Software Center.

Guessing at your specs, you might also have some trouble running Ubuntu with Unity. It is a little greedy on graphics, especially with that graphics card. Xubuntu with the XFCE environment might be a better option.